# Is there an ini setting in php >=5.3.10 that allows paths to behave like php 5.2?

Tags: php

I have a local setup with Apache, php, and oracle. I got the website to run fine, but I am having trouble with running cli mode.

I am using the __autoload function and am running under windows, but the main web server is running off of linux.

At first I set some include paths settings which include paths like: c:\www\mixed\separator/

Now the issue I am running into is that the DIR_SEPARATOR has mixed usage in the code. Due to time constraints, and the fact that it works fine on linux, I don't want to go through all the code to change paths.

So I narrowed it down to what the problem is. Basically, this is trying to load in __autoload:

\Something.php

and in the path, it has c:\www\mixed\seperator/Something.php

The warning is: Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Something.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\www\something/API/') in c:\some\path\to\somefile.php on line 49

So of course while this is a warning it's a "failure" because the file needed is not there.

So what is the difference between php 5.2 and php 5.3? Is there some sort of setting? I'm trying to explore what I can do setting wise and then determine if I need to do code changes.

Please let me know if the above is unclear.

Thanks.

Edit:

To be more specific, it appears in php5.2 paths with mixed separators are forgiven, but in php5.3, it appears that mixed path separators are not as forgiven. Is this something restricted by php 5.3 or is there a setting that enables this? BTW, this is local environment so it's okay since on the real system, the paths will be /www/correct/dir/sep/file.php but on Windows, my local, it will be c:\www\mixed/file.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when referring to system paths. That's what it's there for.